# Splitting a string column according to its values creating new columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a dataframe which looks somthing like this:

```
df
name     age      symptoms
x        18       fever, headache, cough
y        23       cough
z        89       HTN
a        43       TNT, HTN
```

I want to create a new dataframe which looks something like this, depending on the symptoms column.

```
df2
name     age      symptoms                     fever      headache      cough    HTN   TNT
x        18       fever, headache, cough        1          1             1       0      0
y        23       cough                         0          0             1       0      0
z        89       HTN                           0          0             0       1      0
a        43       TNT, HTN                      0          0             0       1      1
```

So it actually creates a new column for every new value found.

I tried it using:

```
split_ = df["symptoms"].str.split(expand=True)
```

but how do I create new columns and add the 0 and 1 value in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pd.DataFrame.join` with `str.get_dummies` with `sep`:

```
df.join(df['symptoms'].str.get_dummies(sep=', '))
```

Output:

```
  name  age                symptoms  HTN  TNT  cough  fever  headache
0    x   18  fever, headache, cough    0    0      1      1         1
1    y   23                   cough    0    0      1      0         0
2    z   89                     HTN    1    0      0      0         0
3    a   43                TNT, HTN    1    1      0      0         0
```

`pd.Series.str.get_dummies` has the `sep` argument, where you could specify the separator you want for `get_dummies`.

Comment: This creates  new column for every combination as well. for eg: for the first row it creates - 4 columns "fever", "headache", "cough" and " fever, headache, cough". what can we change for that?

Comment: @Sahil Well, at least for me it doesn't... Strange.

Comment: @Sahil If so use `df.join(df['symptoms'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')).filter(regex='^[^,]$', axis=1)`

Comment: I figured out my problem. My original string didnt have a space after the comma. Thats why it was creating that many columns, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `pandas.get_dummies` and `join`:

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['symptoms'].str.split(', ').explode()).groupby(level=0).max())
```

output:

```
  name  age                symptoms  HTN  TNT  cough  fever  headache
0    x   18  fever, headache, cough    0    0      1      1         1
1    y   23                   cough    0    0      1      0         0
2    z   89                     HTN    1    0      0      0         0
3    a   43                TNT, HTN    1    1      0      0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['symptoms']))

   name  age                symptoms  HTN  TNT, HTN  cough  \
0    x   18  fever, headache, cough    0         0      0   
1    y   23                   cough    0         0      1   
2    z   89                     HTN    1         0      0   
3    a   43                TNT, HTN    0         1      0   

   fever, headache, cough  
0                       1  
1                       0  
2                       0  
3                       0
```

You could also crosstab

```
pd.crosstab([df.name, df.age], df.symptoms).reset_index()

symptoms name  age  HTN  TNT, HTN  cough  fever, headache, cough
0           a   43    0         1      0                       0
1           x   18    0         0      0                       1
2           y   23    0         0      1                       0
3           z   89    1         0      0                       0
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because there are rows with multiple values.